# Use the ACM ICPS template

Tags: publications, citation-style, acm

I got a paper accepted with the feedback

"Use the ACM ICPS template"

However, I used the latex template found at http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template (\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}) and had followed the ACM citation style... or at least, I thought I had done so.

The feedback does not give any further detail on how the paper has failed to conform to the ACM style. As this seems to be a prerequisite for the camera-ready version, does anyone know how I can work out whether I have adhered to the style demanded, and what steps I must take to fix my paper?

Comment: did you get an aswer or a solution for this problem, because i had the same remark

Comment: @imane bdaw too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACM templates have a number of different options, and it's quite easy to not select something in the variant options that is desired by the particular SIG that you're dealing with.

Double-check the options, and if you still can't figure out how you aren't in compliance, the only thing to do is to write to the folks who sent you that message with a polite question along the lines of:

> "To the best of my knowledge, I am complying with the template.  Can you please let me know what you see that needs to be changed?"